# How to add a value from a text box to list box five times instantly?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, listbox, populate

I like to add textbox4.value to the List box 5 times with one click of a button.
If textbox value is yes, i want the list box to list yes yes yes yes yes. I don't know it this is possible but i hope so.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
If Me.TextBox4.Value = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox4.Value
Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
End If
Me.TextBox4.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If Me.TextBox4.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        ListBox1.AddItem Me.TextBox4.Value
    Next i
    Me.TextBox4.Value = ""
End If
Me.TextBox4.SetFocus

End Sub
```